# ParseUser pinning-saving eventually local datastore error

Tags: android, parse-platform

I started having this error when I enabled the Local Datastore. I don't know how to fix it. I'm looking at documentation, but have found nothing so far... the app doesn't crash, but nothing can be saved to the user object, apparently most of the time.

```
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110): Failed to run command.
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):  com.parse.ParseException:       Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.ParseCommand.onPostExecute(ParseCommand.java:334)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.ParseRequest$5.then(ParseRequest.java:321)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.ParseRequest$5.then(ParseRequest.java:318)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:410)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:402)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
05-03 02:17:24.350: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(1110):    at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
```

I managed to point out the code which produces the error. It has to do with using `saveEventually()` in the current user... it doesn't happen using `saveinbackground()`...

```
ParseUser cu = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 

if (cu != null) {

  String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
  cu.put("locale", locale);
  cu.put("version",            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("appVersion"));
  cu.saveEventually();  //doesn't happen with cu.saveInBackground();
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, did you? please share.

Comment: unfortunately no. i posted a question on Parse. hopefully someone will respond

Comment: did the same, one month ago. Please share if you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Parse Android Changelog**
>
> v1.5.1 — May 30, 2014
>
> Fixed various bugs with Local
>   Datastore.

There were indeed some bugs with the last Parse Android SDK v1.5.0, but for me they got fixed with today's release of the version 1.5.1, you should check it out and try again.

Comment: Just tried, no luck, same error.  It only disappears with .saveinbackground() instead of .saveeventually()  , so there would be a problem in case you´re offline...

Comment: I am also experiencing problems with Local Datastore and SaveEventually, either it hangs, or crashes my app. Currently I have not found a pattern for reliably create objects locally and lazily save to the database (as was expected by SaveEventually to handle)

Comment: I'm experiencing this too with 1.9.0